# Creating a grid of images with a letter on the top left for each one

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

This is the code that I am using now

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l c l c}
      a) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{Black.jpg} &
      b) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{Black.jpg} \\
      c) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{Black.jpg} & 
      d) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{Black.jpg}
 \end{tabularx}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:black}
\end{figure}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I would like to have the letters near the top-left corner of the figures instead of the bottom-left like they are now. How can I do this? Is there a package that makes what I want to do easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one option:  `valign=t` option from `adjustbox` package

```
\documentclass[border=2cm,tikz]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{lclc}
      a) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image} &
      b) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image} \\
      c) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image} & 
      d) & \includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image}
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:black}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]